# How to Deploy website in localhost

Tags: asp.net

I've created one web application in ASP.NET - 2.0 
Now, I want to deploy it in my localhost itself
Is it posible to do so, if yes How it can be achive without having server myself

Comment: It's much easy try it out yourself then tell me roobroo

Answer (score 2):

You will need IIS for this. Which OS are you using? If it is xp then you can install IIS by going to `Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Add/Remove Windows components`. you might need your Windows XP installation cd for installing iis.

After installing you will find iis in `Control Panel -> Administrative tools`

You cannot host a ASP.net site without a server. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 I think by server Hans means an external paid Host. Yes as Shoban suggested you can host your ASP.NET website on the local machine using IIS 5.1 on XP, IIS 6 on Win2k3 & IIS 7 on Vista. Note that this website can be accessed by any computer on the intranet (not only localhost) if you desire.

Comment: Also this may help: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx